# Extending ArrayList and using/creating a similar constructor

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I implemented `ArrayList` here

```
public class JsonList<T> extends ArrayList<T>{
//extended functions

}
```

When creating an ArrayList, you can do something `List<?> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(alreadyCreatedList);`

I want to be able to do this with my JsonList. But currently, JsonList only has the default constructor JsonList<>(). I tried copying the ArrayList constructor like this

```
public JsonList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        elementData = c.toArray();
        if ((size = elementData.length) != 0) {
            // defend against c.toArray (incorrectly) not returning Object[]
            // (see e.g. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6260652)
            if (elementData.getClass() != Object[].class)
                elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, Object[].class);
        } else {
            // replace with empty array.
            this.elementData = EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;
        }
    }
```

And when creating a JsonList instance I do

`JsonList<?> jsonList = new JsonList<>(alreadyCreatedList);`

However, the elements are not saved. It returns an `empty array`. In addition, I can no longer create an empty instance `JsonList<?> jsonList = new JsonList<>();`

**Solution:**
I don't know why I didn't think of it but for those out there here it is

```
public JsonList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    super(c); // <-- invoke the appropriate super constructor
}
```

super(c) is all you need.

Comment: ArrayList had elementdata, size, and EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA declared as variables in that class so I just simply redeclared them in my class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the first line `super(c);` without that, the compiler will insert `super()` which won't invoke the one you want (taking the `Collection<? extends E> c`).

```
public JsonList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    super(c); // <-- invoke the appropriate super constructor
    elementData = c.toArray();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I tried this. But I'm getting errors on my instances declared like this `JsonList<?> filteredList = new JsonList<>();`

Comment: The error says  `JsonList(Collection<? extends E> c) cannot be applied to ()`

Comment: @ReiBrown If you also want an empty constructor, then provide one. If you add a constructor, the compiler no longer inserts the default constructor.